# Carriage returns in DT package R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to display carriage returns using the DT package in an R shiny app?

I have tried the code here:

```
library(DT)

# create data frame with an example column
test_df <- data.frame(SAME =  "Same Line", NEW = "New\nLine")

# print data frame
datatable(test_df)
```

The `\n` notation does not work, and it appears the `datatable` function replaces the `\n` with a space.

I want the second cell "New Line" to have the words "New" and "Line" on separate lines.

Answer (score 13):

This solves the issue:

```
library(DT)

# create data frame with an example column
test_df <- data.frame(SAME =  "Same Line", NEW = "New\nLine")

# replace \n with <br/>
test_df$NEW <- gsub(pattern = "\n", replacement = "<br/>", x = test_df$NEW)

# print data frame 
# with escape set to FALSE
datatable(test_df, escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible version where this does not work?

Comment: You're right, sorry for the cryptic comment... I can and will get back with an example

Comment: I am unsure what the 'escape = F' does. In my own app, when I add escape = false, it returns nothing.The following returns an empty datatable. x is a df, single column with rownames. datatable(x,
                colnames = NULL,
                selection = "single", 
                escape = TRUE,
                options = list(pageLength = -1, 
                               info = FALSE, 
                               dom='t',
                               autoWidth = TRUE,
                               columnDefs = list(list(width = '300px', targets = list(1))))
      )

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution but rather a follow-up to  @easports611 comment. Below is an app where the answer doesn't work:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(data.table)
  data("iris")
    output$buySegments <- DT::renderDataTable({
      colnames(iris)=c("a <br>b","c<br>d","e<br>f","g<br>h","i")
      sketch<-htmltools::withTags(table(
        tableHeader(iris
      )))
      #rangeRatio
      thing = DT::datatable(
        iris
        ,rownames = FALSE
        ,container = sketch
      )
      return(thing)
    }
    )  
}


ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",title = "Buyer Console",
            mainPanel(  
              DT::dataTableOutput('buySegments') 
            )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The issue is clearly the fact that I am specifying the column names via a container. It turns out that the solution is to set `escape = FALSE` option in the `tableHeader()` function.