# How can I split column readers in R?

Tags: r

I would like to split the column readers into two based on a delimiter. From the following df

```
day-W  day-S  nun-W  nun-S 
 1      4      2      5 
 2      4      2      2 
 2      6      3      3
```

What I expect would be:

```
day    day    nun    nun 
 W      S      W      S
 1      4      2      5 
 2      4      2      2 
 2      6      3      3
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, what are you going to do with the expected output? The expected output would change the data structure, all columns will become character.

Comment: Maybe you just want to change how the data is displayed? See related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216290/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the substring from the column names and `rbind` the substring as the first row and then replace the column names with another substring

```
nm1 <- sub("-.*", "", names(df1))
nm2 <- sub(".*-", "", names(df1))
df2 <- rbind(nm2, df1)
names(df2) <- nm1
```

-output

```
df2
#  day day nun nun
#1   W   S   W   S
#2   1   4   2   5
#3   2   4   2   2
#4   2   6   3   3
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to have duplicate column names

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`day-W` = c(1L, 2L, 2L), `day-S` = c(4L, 4L, 6L
), `nun-W` = c(2L, 2L, 3L), `nun-S` = c(5L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```